# AngularJS ng-style background-image

Tags: angularjs

I user AngularJS for setting a background- image but ng-style does not work - style (the second row) works fine. Does anyone have any hint how to get ir work?

```
ng-style="vm.currentUser.sex == 'FEMALE' ? background-image: url(../../../assets/img/female_default.png); : ''"
style="background-image: url(../../../assets/img/female_default.png);"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You expression inside ngStyle directive is messed up. Correct one could be:

```
ng-style="{'background-image': vm.currentUser.sex == 'FEMALE' ? 'url(../../../assets/img/female_default.png)' : 'url(../../../assets/img/male_default.png)'}"
```

If it's hard to read you can either split it into several lines:

```
ng-style="{
    'background-image': vm.currentUser.sex == 'FEMALE' 
        ? 'url(../../../assets/img/female_default.png)' 
        : 'url(../../../assets/img/male_default.png)'
}"
```

or move condition part inside string concatenation:

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(../../../assets/img/' + (vm.currentUser.sex == 'FEMALE' ? 'female' : 'male') + '_default.png)'}"
```

or even

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(../../../assets/img/' + vm.currentUser.sex.toLowerCase() +'_default.png)'}"
```

**However**... You should **avoid** using ngStyles directive for such cases. I would go with two CSS classes for male and female. This is way more flexible:

```
.female {
    backgroind-image: url(../../../assets/img/female_default.png);
}
.male {
    backgroind-image: url(../../../assets/img/male_default.png);
}
```

and use ngClass directive:

```
ng-class="vm.currentUser.sex.toLowerCase()"
```